# Is there any way stop my Apple trackpad from rotating?

Tags: hardware, magic-trackpad

My Apple trackpad seems to rotate counter clockwise (I am right handed) through my use of it over the day. This happens several times normally during the day. It never used to do so when it was new but it is doing it now and I am using the same desk.

I have cleaned all the contacts but it doesn't seem to help, maybe I am not cleaning it right. I would be interested to know the best cleaning methods if you think this is where I am going wrong.

My use of it may have changed too so if you think this might be a problem of the way my trackpad usage has developed please note that too. The weather has changed too over the time since I have got it and although we normally run air conditioning within my office the temperatures at night might become too extreme for it.

Is there an easy way to anchor it to the desk?

Comment: Should this be on Ask Different? Anyway, it's probably your trackpad usage developing that's caused the issue. Maybe tape it to the table (I know it's tacky, but...) or use a mouse mat.

Comment: I've read the faq and this question is clearly a `practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face` about `apple hardware` and isn't covered by any exception on that page.

Answer (score 2):

Get a rubber mat for it to stand on, or as Faiz mentioned in a comment, use small amounts of tape to make it stick to your desk.

The rubber contacts on most Apple products can become a bit slippery after use. I personally just rub off any dirt that has collected over time with my thumb, and it's back to normal – slip-free.

Something like [these Anti Slip Mats](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5pcs-Anti-Slip-Mat-Magic-Sticky-Pad-Car-Dashboard-Non-slip-Phone-Six-colour-/160975828575?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item257ae8365f) on Ebay should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you also use an Apple Bluetooth keyboard, the [Twelve South Magic Wand](http://store.apple.com/us/product/H3443ZM/A/twelve-south-magicwand) that attaches the KB & TP side-by-side is one solution.